# SQL Statement Issue combining 4 tables to get the correct information to display

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns

I am having trouble figuring this one out. I'm using MS SQL 2008 and trying to add the total tech hours from the unbilled table and the billed tables and group them together.  I also need to exclude rows for the billed hours based on the report header on a third table if the billed report is voided.  I then need to grab the tech names from a 4th table.  The unbilled table is SCQReportLabors which lists all the labor records. SCReportLabors table lists all the billed labor records.  SCReports is the billed report header which I need to figure out if the VoidID column is null.  ShAgents table holds the tech names.  Below is what I currently have and I know it doesn't work but it's what I've got so far.  For my output data I woul like a TotalHours column and a TechName column.  If I end up with a billed total, unbilled total and techname column I can live with that as well.  I've been staring at this for a little while and need some perspective and advice.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
SELECT a.TotalHours, c.PrefFullName AS TechName
    FROM (SELECT SUM(LaborHours)+SUM(OvertimeHours)+SUM(TravelHours) AS TotalHours, TechnicianID 
        FROM SCReportLabors
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SCReports d ON a.ReportID = d.ReportID
    WHERE d.VoidID IS NULL
    GROUP BY TechnicianID) a
    JOIN (SELECT SUM(LaborHours)+SUM(OvertimeHours)+SUM(TravelHours) AS TotalHours, TechnicianID
      FROM SCQReportLabors
      GROUP BY TechnicianID) b
ON a.TechnicianID = b.TechnicianID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ShAgents c ON a.TechnicianID = c.AgentID
ORDER BY c.PrefFullName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should capture all data and handles null hours.

```
SELECT
    A.PrefFullName AS 'TechName',
    (ISNULL(B.TotalHours, 0) + ISNULL(C.TotalHours, 0)) AS 'Total Hours'
FROM
    ShAgents AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT 
                (
                    SUM(ISNULL(LaborHours, 0)) + 
                    SUM(ISNULL(OvertimeHours, 0)) + 
                    SUM(ISNULL(TravelHours, 0))
                ) AS 'TotalHours', 
                TechnicianID 
            FROM 
                SCReportLabors AS tA
                LEFT OUTER JOIN SCReports AS tB
                    ON tA.ReportID = tB.ReportID
            WHERE 
                tB.VoidID IS NULL
            GROUP BY 
                TechnicianID
        ) AS B
        ON A.AgentID = B.TechnicianID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT 
                (
                    SUM(ISNULL(LaborHours, 0)) + 
                    SUM(ISNULL(OvertimeHours, 0)) + 
                    SUM(ISNULL(TravelHours, 0))
                ) AS 'TotalHours', 
                TechnicianID
            FROM 
                SCQReportLabors
            GROUP BY 
                TechnicianID
        ) AS C
        ON A.AgentID = C.TechnicianID
ORDER BY 
    A.PrefFullName
```

Comment: Thanks Chris and David.  I like catching the NULL's in Chris's example something I hadn't considered yet but the lines ) AS 'TotalHours', on line 13 and 32 pop as incorrect syntax and I'm not sure why.  I ran it through the query analyzer.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @pdmarty I was missing a close parenthesis on each line. Code in answer has been updated.

Comment: Thanks Chris. After taking a second look at it I too noticed that. I also added ON a.agentID = c.TechnicianID to the second left join.  The issue I have now is it won't bind the a.reportID if the first left join and it can't seem to find the TravelHours column in the first left join. This column does exist and I don't see why it won't bind. I'll have to do a little digging on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I made the two main queries a UNION query and also touched up on JOIN for the VOID column.

```
SELECT SQ1.TotalHours, SHA.PrefFullName AS TechName
FROM
(
SELECT SUM(TOTALHOURS) AS TotalHours, TechnicianID
    (SELECT SUM(LaborHours)+SUM(OvertimeHours)+SUM(TravelHours) AS TotalHours, TechnicianID 
    FROM SCReportLabors L
    JOIN SCReports RPTS
    ON L.ReportID = RPTS.ReportID
    WHERE RPTS.VoidID IS NULL
    GROUP BY TechnicianID)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(LaborHours)+SUM(OvertimeHours)+SUM(TravelHours) AS TotalHours, TechnicianID
     FROM SCQReportLabors
     GROUP BY TechnicianID
     )
) SQ
GROUP BY TechnicianID
JOIN ShAgents SHA
ON SQ.TechnicianID = SHA.AgentID
ORDER BY SHA.PrefFullName
```